# joining an azure vm to a customers azure ad

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

we have a customer that has office 365 azure AD. we are planning to host our application for them on an azure vm. Our application needs to be domain joined so that the customer can log into the app using there onpremise AD credentials.

how can we accomplish this?

Comment: Were you able to solve this? I am in a similar situation.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're searching for Azure connect which will integrate your on-premises directories with Azure Active Directory.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-aadconnect/

Comment: I thank you but I dont believe that was what I was asking. The customer will be using ad connect for their on premise ad and azure ad integration. we would have an azure vm server with our app installed which would need to join their Azure Ad. is this possible